# jCarouselLite show active element first

Tags: jquery, jcarousellite

I have a carousel which uses the jCarouselLite script, the carousel is used as a sub menu on a page.

Now after clicking a element from the carousel the **li** gets an class of **active** the're 4 visible elements.

I wan't to be able to scroll to the active element on page load so it is visible to the user.

I tried the **btnGo** option but the number of items can change (as in a menu), and with triggering the **click** event a number of times on the **next** button as shown below, but the event can be triggered once after that it dosn't work.

```
  $('.slideshow').jCarouselLite({
      btnNext: "#next",
      btnPrev: "#prev",
      visible:4,
      circular: false,
      mouseWheel: true,
      btnGo:[".slideshow li.active"]
   });

    //scroll to active element
    var activePosition = $('.slideshow ul li.active').position();
    if (activePosition != null) {
    var index = $('.slideshow ul li.active').index();

    for (var i = index-4; i >= 0; i--) {
      $('#next').trigger('click').delay( 800 );
     }
    };
```

Can this be done in any way??

Answer (score 0):

To solve this a actually replaced the lite version with jCarousel which has a built in function to go to position (index) of the carousel example shown below.

```
var activePosition = $('.slideshow ul li.active').position();
  if (activePosition != null) {
    var index = $('.slideshow ul li.active').index();
    $('.slideshow').jcarousel('scroll',index);
  };
```